# Ocultar linhas do Datagridview por comparação de data

Tags: c#, datagridview

Olá! Preciso ocultar certas linhas do `DataGridView` que contenha na coluna `data` uma data menor que a data atual. Achei este código, porém não sei como ocultar as linhas com essa comparação, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
private void dgvDados_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dgvDados.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        DateTime DataViagem = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvDados.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["data"].Value.ToString());
        DateTime DataAtual = DateTime.Now.Date;

        if (DataViagem <= DataAtual)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Para evitar erro caso a linha selectionada seja para esconder.    
dgvDados.CurrentCell = null;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDados.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["data"].Value is DateTime)
    {
        DateTime d = (DateTime)row.Cells["data"].Value;
        if (d <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu erro nessa parte: `if (row.Cells["data"].Value is DateTime d && d < DateTime.Now)`: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. E esse também: The name 'd' does not exist in the current context

Comment: actualizei a resposta, que versão do c# você usa?

Comment: Visual Studio C# 2012

Comment: Esse erro ocorreu na linha `dgvDados.CurrentCell = null;`, erro: A operação não é válida porque resulta em uma chamada reentrante para a função SetCurrentCellAddressCore.